# TinyMCE: How disable merge p element with div element before

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

TinyMCE: How disable merge p element with div element before?

div may have specific class

if possible use some callback

before

```
<div class="XXX mceNonEditable">text text text text</div> [CURSOR]
<p>[CURSOR]123 123 123 123 123</p>
```

after i set cursor and press backspace - tags merge

```
<div class="XXX mceNonEditable">text text text text[CURSOR]123 123 123 123 123</div>
```

Comment: we need a somewhat better explanation of what you want to achieve and what you tried and what the result was, noone will be able to reply to this few information.

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behavior. P-Tag and Divs are elements that are used to hold the lines of text or other contents that are hold inside the editor. Because you deleted the opening p-tag everything gets merged into the div-tag. I suggest that you only use one kind of block-element to hold the line contents - eighter ps or divs.

Did you expect any other behavior?

Comment: I have no expectations. I just need to uneditable block was not really edited and therefore didn't stick together.

Comment: so which behavior do you want? it might be possible to interfer with the default behavior

Comment: Have you added any function on keypress event ?

Comment: usually i do not put any function onkeypress, cause keycodes are not set onkeypressed in firefox